# SQL get information from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database from which I need to `JOIN` 4 tables and I am having some trouble figuring it out

I have the following tables

```
A. id, name, picture, d_id
B. id, name
C. id, a_id, b_id, commentaar
D. id, name
```

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? `A` has data used in `D` and `C` has data used in `A` and `B`, so I am at a loss how to get this one done. I want to output

```
A.name, A.picture, B.Name, C.commentaar, D.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need to do this:

```sql
Select  A.name, A.picture, B.Name, C.commentaar, D.name
From    A
Join    D   On  A.d_id = D.id
Join    C   On  C.a_id = A.id
Join    B   On  C.b_id = B.id
```